# Чем удалить лишние иконки из шрифта?

Tags: шрифты, поиск-программ

Применяю fontawesome иконки, необходимо удалить более чем 70% иконок. Дабы вес файла уменьшить.

Многие сервисы перепробовал, но толком не нашел.

Чем открыть файл woff2?

И возможно применить несколько цветов для отдельной иконки?

Comment: FontForge пробовали?

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает. Вопрос, при работе с иконками. Не возможно одной иконке придать 3-5 и более цветов. Только если назначать через after и before и то в данном случаи доступно будет 2 цвета.

Comment: Лучше задайте новый вопрос, а не пишите в комментариях, так его никто не увидит. Я в вебе не разбираюсь, но не могу даже представить, что значит назначить иконке несколько цветов. Что должно получится в итоге? Тем более, в FontAwesome они все, вроде плоские.

Comment: @eanmos, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, про цвета к теме вопроса вообще никак не относится.